# apache mod_rewrite / mod_proxy adds port 443 to proxy url on https to http

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

We are using mod_rewrite with mod_proxy to proxy requests by crawlers and bots to prerender.io. The prerender service does not support https currently, but my clients site only does, so the proxy is from https to http.
This used to work fine but since we updated to Apache 2.4.29 the proxy urls always have port 443 added.

```
Old: https://www.example.com/news/something -> http://service.prerender.io/https://www.example.com/news/something
New: https://www.example.com/news/something -> http://service.prerender.io:443/https://www.example.com/news/something
```

How can I revert back to the old behavior without reverting apache?

Heres the .htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot|bingbot|baiduspider|rogerbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Yandex(Bot|Images|Video|Media) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://service.prerender.io/https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: Which version of Apache were you upgrading from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very straight forward and easy, probably why I missed it.

Just add port 80 to the proxy url:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot|bingbot|baiduspider|rogerbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Yandex(Bot|Images|Video|Media) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://service.prerender.io:80/https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [P,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any differences between Apache 2.4.29 and Apache 2.2 in this regard, however, if you are upgrading from Apache 2.0 (or even earlier?) then there are changes in the defaults.

If you don't explicitly include the port number in the substitution URL then Apache 2.2+ will derive the port number from the [`ServerName`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername), [`UseCanonicalName`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#usecanonicalname) and [`UseCanonicalPhysicalPort`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#usecanonicalphysicalport) directives and/or the request. On Apache 2.0 the *default* for `UserCanonicalName` was `On` (`UseCanonicalPhysicalPort` was only introduced in Apache 2.2) - this changed to `Off` in later versions of Apache - so, unless you explicitly set this it would use the port from the request instead.

So, if you are experiencing a difference after a server update then I would suspect a change to one of these directives, unless you are upgrading from a very old version of Apache.